# Refreshing component observable with new API URL from another component in Ionic2/Angular2 refreshing

Tags: modal-dialog, angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I am struggling with an Ionic2/Angular2 problem that is probably straight forward but I just cannot see the solution.

I have a component called Recipes that consumes data from an API call in a service called DataService. This is all good.

Then I have another component that is displayed in a modal launched from Recipes. This component has controls that modify the API query (ie, the URL called). When the user closes the modal I want to refresh the data in Recipes by calling the API with the new URL but cannot figure out how to make this work.

Below is my recipes.ts which contains the classes for Recipes and the modal and my data.ts which contains the DataService code.

Recipes.ts:

```
import {Page, Modal, ViewController, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from '../../service/data.ts';
import {Http, Headers, Request, RequestOptions, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/recipes/recipes.html'
})
export class RecipesPage {
  constructor(nav: NavController, dataService: DataService) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.dataService = dataService;
    this.results = [];
    this.connectData();
  }

  // open filters modal
  openFilters(filters) {
      let modal = Modal.create(filterModal, this.filters);
      this.nav.present(modal);
  }

  connectData() {
    this.dataService.getData('initialQuery')
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
      console.log(this.results);
    })
  }

}

// modal logic
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/recipes/recipes-modal.html'
})
export class RecipesModal {
  constructor(nav: NavController, params: NavParams, viewCtrl: ViewController, dataService: DataService) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.dataService = dataService;
    this.params = params;
    this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
  }

  close() {
    this.dataService.getData('nextQuery');
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    // how do I update the data displayed by Recipes when this modal is closed?
  }
}
```

data.ts:

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, Request, RequestOptions, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  // function to
  getData(keyword) {
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      method: RequestMethod.Get,
      url: 'https://api/' + keyword,
    });
    let request = new Request(options);
    return this.http.request(request)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Please let me know what I have missed here...

Answer (score 0):

In fact when calling the dismiss method, you can provide data. I would your code this way:

```
  close() {
    this.dataService.getData('nextQuery').subscribe(data => {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
    });
  }
```

And you can receive the data this way in this other component:

```
  openFilters(filters) {
      let modal = Modal.create(filterModal, this.filters);
      modal.onDismiss(data => {
        this.result = data;
      });
      this.nav.present(modal);
  }
```

See this documentation:

- http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/Modal/

Comment: Thanks Thierry! I did read that documentation but somehow just totally missed the part about modals emitting data. Problem solved